# how can I add index as key value in a list of dict in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a list like below -

```
[{'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z'}, {'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z'},
{'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z'}]
```

Need to add index key and its value in these three records.
Expected output -

```
[{'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z','index':0}, {'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z','index':1},
{'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z','index':2}]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [
{"amount": 1100000, "target": 120000, "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
{"amount": 1100000, "target": 120000, "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
{"amount": 1100000, "target": 120000, "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i]['index']=i
print(lst)
```

> **Output**

```
[{'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, 'time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'index': 0}, {'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, 'time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'index': 1}, {'amount': 1100000, 'target': 120000, 'time': '2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'index': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {"amount": 1100000, "target": 120000, "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"amount": 1100000, "target": 120000, "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"amount": 1100000, "target": 120000, "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"},
]

for idx, d in enumerate(lst):
    d["index"] = idx

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "amount": 1100000,
        "target": 120000,
        "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "index": 0,
    },
    {
        "amount": 1100000,
        "target": 120000,
        "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "index": 1,
    },
    {
        "amount": 1100000,
        "target": 120000,
        "time": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "index": 2,
    },
]
```